# PowerShell Script to manipulate delimited text file

Tags: powershell

I need a script preferably in PowerShell to create an output text file based on my source text file.
I have blocks of data in my file separated by one blank line which also need to remove.
There are two types of blocks as you can see below. 
I have multiple lines below the  "!JOURNAL" tag. 
I do not need the "!DESC" information.
On Block1 I only need to flip the sign on the numeric column/field depending on the initial character of my no 2 field i.e. if it starts with '5' and 'D' the flip the sign -100725.836.
On Block2 I need to flip the sign as in Block1 and also pickup the last field  and put it on the line "BRAZHOLD".

Can you please help? 
Thank you

[image]

Comment: start working with Get-Content to read the file into an array.  Use a loop to iterate over each line.  Use RegEx or wildcard matching to identify lines containing the data you want to modify:  if ($LineInLoop -match '^\!JOURNAL') { #do work to change line }

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60820152/edit) your question and put the file in as **TEXT**, not as image so we can work on it. Also, Show us what the desired output should look like, because your description puzzles me somewhat (or is that just me?)